# cannot execute binary file on a solaris system - over ssh

Tags: c

I try to compile and execute a c-written program and I get the error message written in the topic.

I am logged in over SSH, go to the directory where my method is, and compile it with:

```
gcc -o exec -c main.c
```

Which generates the "exec" file. Then I put the rights:

```
chmod u+x exec
```

And when I try to run it with ./exec i get the error message :S.. What do I miss here :S??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gcc with flag `-c` compiles to an object, and not to a runnable binary. If you want to binary, omit this flag.

Change to:

```
gcc -o exec main.c
```

Comment: Thanks. that was the problem,

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `-c` option, which tells `gcc` to generate an *object* file. Object files are files which can be used with the linker to create the final executable program.

So the solution is to either drop the `-c` option, in which case `gcc` will generate a temporary object file (which it then deletes) and do linking in one step. Or you link separately in a separate step after compiling:

```
$ gcc -o main.o -c main.c
$ gcc -o exec main.o
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compile your main.c file as **gcc -o exec main.c** as -c option is for
    -c         Compile or assemble the source files, but do not link.  The linking
               stage simply is not done.  The ultimate output is in the form of an
               object file for each source file.
               By default, the object file name for a source file is made by
               replacing the suffix .c, .i, .s, etc., with .o.